# Function expected error in an addEventListener block of code

Tags: javascript, function, windows-runtime, windows-phone, winjs

I am developing a Windows Phone app and using HTML/JS to build it. So there is a WinJS reference in my code.

The following is my code:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("...", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        var item = element.querySelector("#item").winControl;
        item.addEventListener("iteminvoked", function (eventInfo) {
            eventInfo.detail.itemPromise.done(function itemInvoked(item) {
                WinJS.Navigation.navigate("...", { newsItem: item.data });
            });
        }, false);
    }
}
```

When I ran the code above, it threw the error, saying: `0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected` and it lead to base.js, which is part of the WinJS language (correct me if I'm wrong). I used breakpoints and "step over" line-by-line and the line before which the error was thrown is: `item.addEventListener...`.

I tried using http://jshint.com and it didn't show any errors, apart from unused variables and undefined variables (WinJS).

Please let me know if I need to show more code.

When I searched for this problem, I learned that it might be because I added a paranthesis somewhere where I wasn't supposed to, hence it's treating it as a function.

Comment: Why not document.getElementById?

Comment: Is `item.addEventListener` a function? How about `eventInfo.detail.itemPromise.done`?

Comment: @bjb568 I found querySelector to be quicker, but I don't think one over the other would make much of a difference, would it?

Comment: @DemCodeLines querySelector is not quicker. getElementById is faster and easier to understand.

Comment: @false Yes, under the WinJS api, they are.

Comment: @DemCodeLines Windows is screwed up.

Comment: Uhh, but that doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe another typo, last line ought to be `});` not a single curly brace.

Comment: Also, do you have a `data-win-control` attribute on your `#item` element?

Answer (score 2):

your missing a curly bracket

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("...", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        var item = element.querySelector("#item").winControl;
        item.addEventListener("iteminvoked", function (eventInfo) {
            eventInfo.detail.itemPromise.done(function itemInvoked(item) {
                WinJS.Navigation.navigate("...", { newsItem: item.data });
            });
        }, false);
    } // HERE
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I just copied it wrong. I have updated the code.